# Как закрыть html-файл от неавторизованного доступа?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Изначально имеется файл index.html, в котором вызывается js-скрипт, посредством которого отрисовывается содержимое страницы и реализован её функционал. Затем понадобилась работа с БД на стороне сервера и появилась авторизация, поэтому главным файлом-контроллером стал файл index.php, который уже перенаправляет пользователя на страницу авторизации, а если он авторизован, то, в соответствии с его ролью, на страницу админки admin.php или тот самый изначальный index.html.
И если прямой неавторизованный доступ в админку по адресу в URL-строке http://localhost/templates/admin.php я легко закрыл

`if(!isLogin($link)) header('Location: /');`

то как аналогично закрыть http://localhost/table/index.html никак допереть не могу.

Функция isLogin() в php-файле возвращает true\false в зависимости от того авторизовался юзер или нет.
Переписать файл index.html в index.php не позволяет религия. Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^table/index.html$ table/_index.php
```

`_index.php`

```
//Проверка на авторизацию
if(!isLogin($link))
    //Вывод файла index.html
    print file_get_contents("index.html");
```

Comment: То есть "легальных" способов все же нет, верно? Только редирект, который в данном случае  - суть костыль решения "переписать старый index.html на newPage.php"? 
В целом я использовал ваш способ чтобы поиграться с .htaccess, в котором ранее начинал настраивать редиректы по 404 и 500, но видимо позже перепишу всё же чтобы не плодить зоопарк разных расширений. Благодарю!

Comment: Если не трудно, ответь на вопросы в камменте выше.

Comment: @Sage нет, ничего ненужно переписывать и переделывать в исходном `index. html` на `newPage.php`. `_index.php` производит проверку на авторизацию и отдаёт файл `index. html` клиенту. это не то что бы редирект со страницы на страницу - сервер сразу исполняет файл `_index.php`.